# Counting binary forms inside of an orbit having bounded height

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $V_n(\mathbb{Z})$ denote the $\mathbb{Z}$-lattice of integral binary $n$-ic forms: that is,

$$\displaystyle V_n(\mathbb{Z}) = \{a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} y + \cdots + a_0 y^n : a_i \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \leq i \leq n \}.$$

The group $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on $V_n(\mathbb{Z})$ by substitution.

We denote by $H(f) = \max\{|a_n|, \cdots, |a_0|\}$ for the (naive) height of an element $f \in V_n \mathbb{Z}$.

Now fix $f \in V_n(\mathbb{Z})$, not identically zero. Let $O(f)$ denote the orbit of $f$ under $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Do we know how to count

$$\displaystyle \{g \in O(f) : H(g) \leq X\}?$$